# Trying to prove this statement about inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

This is from Spivak, this is not homework (just a little fun in my spare time,) and I'd prefer a hint to a full-blown solution. I've been stuck on this for couple days:

Prove that if $$|x-x_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}$$and$$|x-x_0|<1$$ and $$|y-y_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$$
then $$|xy-x_0y_0|<\epsilon$$

I've tried various ways of writing $xy-x_0y_0$ as $(x-x_0)$ and $(y-y_0)$ though wasn't able to come up with anything particularly promising...

As always, I'm probably being a little special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof:

$|x| - |x_0| < |x - x_0|$ < 1 $\Rightarrow$ $|x| < |x_0| + 1$, and $|y_0| < |y_0| + 1$. So using triangle inequality:
$|xy - x_0y_0| = |x(y - y_0) + y_0(x - x_0)| < |x|(|y - y_0|) + |y_0|(|x - x(0)|) <(|x_0| + 1)\frac{e}{2}\frac{1}{|x_0| + 1} + (|y_0|+1)\frac{e}{2}\frac{1}{|y_0| + 1} < e/2 + e/2 = e$.

Comment: What are those /'s everywhere?

Comment: @Siminore: it's the absolute value / /